# Do changes in the access.conf file require a reboot?

Tags: linux, security

I am using centos 6, from the [manual pages](https://linux.die.net/man/5/access.conf) it has not mentioned that changes require reboot.

> Does it even require a reboot ? or saving the file is enough for the
>   new changes to take place ?

Comment: AFAIK, saving the file is sufficient for new login attempts.

Comment: I have tested myself with added uses for cron , reboot of the system is not required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Access.conf changes do not require reboot. However, if you are adding a new group or changing group membership via LDAP and running nscd, you might have to restart the nscd service.